least squares minimum test error solution
assume we want to learn a model $y=x^T \beta + \varepsilon $
where

$\beta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is constant
$ x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the input vector with Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma_x)$ i.e. $x$ is zero mean and $d \times d$ covariance matrix $\Sigma_x$, assume $\Sigma_x$ is invertible and positive-definite.
$\varepsilon ~ \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_\varepsilon)$
$y \in \mathbb{R}$ is the output corresponding to the input $x$
we donote the training input matrix as $\hat{X} = [x_1, ...,x_n]^T$ and the out vector as $\hat{y} = [y_1, ...,y_n]^T$
assume that $n < d$

consider the learning  of a model $\hat{f}(x) = \hat{\alpha}^Tx$ such that $\hat{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is an interpolating solution in the sense of $\hat{X}\hat{\alpha}=\hat{y}$
the optimal interpolating solution achieves the minimum test error: $$\hat{\alpha}_{opt} = \underset{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\mathrm{argmin}} {\epsilon_{\mathrm{test}} (\alpha)}$$
subject to $\hat{X}\alpha=\hat{y}$
where $\epsilon_{\mathrm{test}} (\alpha) = \mathbb{E}_{x,y}[(\alpha^Tx-y)^2]$
I managed to prove that $$\epsilon_{\mathrm{test}}(\alpha) = \|\Sigma_x^{1/2}(\alpha -\beta)\|_2^2 + \sigma _\epsilon^2$$ and i need to prove $$\epsilon_{\mathrm{test}}(\alpha_\mathrm{opt}) = \epsilon^T(RR^T)^{-1}\epsilon + \sigma_\epsilon^2$$ where $$\epsilon_{\mathrm{test}}(\alpha_{\mathrm{opt}})\leq \epsilon_{\mathrm{test}}(\alpha)$$ for any iterpolution solution $\alpha$
where $\epsilon = [\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n]^T$ is an noise vector including the noise component in the training data. i need to express $R$ explicitly in terms of $\hat{X} \Sigma_x^{1/2}, \Sigma_x$ and basic mathematical elements and operators.
